Is there a way to build a 360* plot in r?
This is all i have so far:
data2 <- data.frame(time = c(ts_nodates), bearing = c(T6PO_Clean$bearing))

ggplot(data2, aes(x = bearing, y = time, fill = factor(bearing))) 
+     geom_col(width = 5)   
+     scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 359, by = 10), limits = c(-10, 350)) 
+     coord_polar(start = -pi/18, clip = "off")

Result:

I'm trying to get more of a line graph as well as opposed to the picture!
Tried and want to get continuous line on a 360 degree graph, got something weird.
Edit: This is a picture of what i want graph to look like:
enter image description here

It looks like your data was imported incorrectly. It doesn't appear to be numeric to R. How did you import your data? It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

@MrFlick More likely, the error comes from a coercion to factor in fill = factor(bearing).

It's not clear to me at all what output you want to get. If you are trying to get a line graph, use geom_line, or perhaps geom_polygon if you want to "complete" the circle.

@Axeman I am working on a project where i am collecting data from my phone. The phone is held straight up and down. The factor (bearing) would br the degrees the front of the phone is pointing from true north. I am unsure how to portray this using a graph

@axeman i want to show how that bearing changes over time. My skill level with R is very low so i am unfamiliar on the graphing process - if you need more info let me know


You should include a minimal and reproducible example. In your case, focus on including relevant example data as described in the link. 2) An image or drawing of the kind of plot you are going for would greatly help.


Take a look at some of the plot funcs available in the package plotrix . There are some decent 360-degree plotters there.

@Axeman - sorry for long delay - i included a picture of what i would prefer graph to look like! as a beginner, not sure how to, or if it's even possible at all - edit in original post
